# Calculating number of times a game was played

Tags: mysql, sql

```
I would like to know the number of times each game is played.

I need result like this :

------------------------------------------------------

    Games                             Count
    ---------                       ---------
    Ag Across America                   5
    geam 2                              7
    game 3                             10   


Background info:

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;



    INSERT INTO `maf_game` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'Ag Across America');


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game_attempts` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `userid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `sessionid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `attempttime` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;




    INSERT INTO `maf_game_attempts` (`id`, `userid`, `sessionid`, `gid`, `status`, `attempttime`) VALUES
    (1, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 18:58:14'),
    (2, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 18:59:02'),
    (3, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 18:59:33'),
    (4, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:00:41'),
    (5, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:38'),
    (6, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:44'),
    (7, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:48'),
    (8, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:49'),
    (9, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:54'),
    (10, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:02:08'),
    (11, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:02:09'),
    (12, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:02:10'),
    (13, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:02:15'),
    (14, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:02:18'),
    (15, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 'Done', '2013-03-25 19:02:20'),
    (16, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:50:30'),
    (17, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:50:37'),
    (18, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:50:45'),
    (19, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:50:51'),
    (20, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:52:58'),
    (21, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:53:01'),
    (22, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:53:08');


    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game_stats` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `userid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `sessionid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `qid` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `result` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `accesstime` datetime NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=23 ;


    INSERT INTO `maf_game_stats` (`id`, `userid`, `sessionid`, `gid`, `qid`, `result`, `accesstime`) VALUES
    (1, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 16, '0', '2013-03-25 18:58:14'),
    (2, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 14, '0', '2013-03-25 18:59:02'),
    (3, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 12, '1', '2013-03-25 18:59:33'),
    (4, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 9, '0', '2013-03-25 19:00:41'),
    (5, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 5, '0', '2013-03-25 19:01:37'),
    (6, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 6, '0', '2013-03-25 19:01:43'),
    (7, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-25 19:01:48'),
    (8, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 9, '0', '2013-03-25 19:01:49'),
    (9, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 14, '1', '2013-03-25 19:01:54'),
    (10, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 15, '1', '2013-03-25 19:02:08'),
    (11, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 7, '0', '2013-03-25 19:02:09'),
    (12, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 6, '1', '2013-03-25 19:02:10'),
    (13, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 14, '0', '2013-03-25 19:02:15'),
    (14, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 6, '0', '2013-03-25 19:02:18'),
    (15, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 13, '1', '2013-03-25 19:02:20'),
    (16, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 6, '0', '2013-03-25 19:50:30'),
    (17, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 9, '0', '2013-03-25 19:50:37'),
    (18, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 1, '1', '2013-03-25 19:50:45'),
    (19, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 4, '0', '2013-03-25 19:50:51'),
    (20, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 16, '0', '2013-03-25 19:52:58'),
    (21, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 13, '0', '2013-03-25 19:53:01'),
    (22, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 1, '0', '2013-03-25 19:53:08');

-------------------------------
Q:Yester day Query good but i need without ending "Over" , "Done" anonomous user like 
"sessionid " uj24ookkdcr3ris0cpbf82dd14 his user have 1 attempt and eqs39lv506p150esr274e9a810 user have 1 one attempt,  any help please...?


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


INSERT INTO `maf_game` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Ag Across America');



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `maf_game_attempts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sessionid` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `attempttime` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=31 ;

INSERT INTO `maf_game_attempts` (`id`, `userid`, `sessionid`, `gid`, `status`, `attempttime`) VALUES
(1, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 18:58:14'),
(2, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 18:59:02'),
(3, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 18:59:33'),
(4, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:00:41'),
(5, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:38'),
(6, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:44'),
(7, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:48'),
(8, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:49'),
(9, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:01:54'),
(10, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:02:08'),
(11, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:02:09'),
(12, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:02:10'),
(13, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'tpv2ebuhtnv5a8thfmltarsl65', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:02:15'),
(14, 'AXDUYNBAUIGC268', 'o9u8tno9qvrj8cfja2g1c516f5', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:02:18'),
(15, 'ZKHBILGVNJBB040', '8h8r13pnad0ftitsdjt9co49p0', 1, 'Done', '2013-03-25 19:02:20'),
(16, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:50:30'),
(17, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:50:37'),
(18, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:50:45'),
(19, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'hcn27d3i1kemmgubvti8ic3p87', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:50:51'),
(20, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:52:58'),
(21, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 'start', '2013-03-25 19:53:01'),
(22, 'JOQHOIGNUFEC945', 'bb57a1nfodomuf0i01pcojs0f2', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-25 19:53:08'),
(23, 'GXJVKQTQIJMU436', 'uj24ookkdcr3ris0cpbf82dd14', 1, 'start', '2013-03-26 10:02:02'),
(24, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'eqs39lv506p150esr274e9a810', 1, 'start', '2013-03-26 10:05:06'),
(25, 'PEHICJWEBEGA391', 'eqs39lv506p150esr274e9a810', 1, 'start', '2013-03-26 10:05:12'),
(26, 'EHHYWVGQZKLA633', 'cptl7mvvb88r764n0654avc1l5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-26 10:17:40'),
(27, 'EHHYWVGQZKLA633', 'cptl7mvvb88r764n0654avc1l5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-26 10:17:47'),
(28, 'EHHYWVGQZKLA633', 'cptl7mvvb88r764n0654avc1l5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-26 10:17:56'),
(29, 'EHHYWVGQZKLA633', 'cptl7mvvb88r764n0654avc1l5', 1, 'Over', '2013-03-26 10:18:05'),
(30, 'EHHYWVGQZKLA633', 'cptl7mvvb88r764n0654avc1l5', 1, 'start', '2013-03-26 10:18:17');
```

Comment: What's the actual question?

Comment: typically - you would show what you have attempted, and where you are stuck. - this is a SQL statement - have you tried any?

Comment: select gid, count(*) from maf_game_attempts group by gid? This is a guess based on the limited information provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short here is how is possible to make it:

```
Select maf_game.name as daname , count(maf_game_attempts.id) as danum from maf_game,maf_game_attempts where maf_game_attempts.gid=maf_game.id and maf_game_attempts.status='over';
```

You can discard status over or change it to what you need I assume that over means played.

Comment: Although simple it is some kind useful question for the beginner!

Comment: And that's the real answer dude!